# Blank space under body in Chrome Device Mode

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why there is a blank space under `body` tag on mobile view ( chrome only, ff and ie work fine )

the code is simple:

```
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<head></head>
<style>
    body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    width: 500%;
    background: pink}
</style>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

image:

[image]

Comment: Also after refreshing the page, as suggested by the browser?

Comment: Your device defines height with 1024 px

Comment: I can replicate that by scrolling down, so I doubt it's really there. It's just the Chrome canvas.

Comment: @blckbird like I said the prob is only on chrome, firefox/ie it work fine there is no blank space

Comment: @Roope yes dude, but on firefox or ie u cant scroll down that's mean it work fine

Comment: Depending on your preferences, you could always add `user-scalable=no` to the meta tag. On a side note, your styles should probably be inside the head tags.

Comment: Try to add span element inside body and give it a fixed postion with css it goes to blank space, so u can't see it

Comment: @Roope is completely correct. Look at your image: on the left hand side there is a ruler. The pink stops at roughly 1024 which is the Apple iPad's screen resolution. You've either scrolled beyond what you've defined (height:100%) or you're zoomed out so of course you wont see anything. By the looks of things you've simply scrolled down. Or am I misunderstanding something here?

Answer (score 0):

It's just the Chrome device view. You have scrolled the view down. The screen height is set at 1024px, so the body won't go any lower. There's no need to worry since you won't be able to scroll down once you have it opened on an actual device. **It's just the Chrome viewer, there's nothing wrong with your site.**

**Edit:**
I noticed you had solved it by using a fixed position. You shouldn't do that. It won't be useful in normal use, and might lead to problems in later development.